# How do I retrieve GET data after I use mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

But now, $_GET statements do not work.  If I have an url `http://localhost/home/index?var=3`, $_GET contains only the value "home/index".  I'm not familiar with this so I don't know how to change it.

How do I enable $_GET statements in my urls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]` to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

it will now append the query string. `QSA` means `Query String Append`.